# Arrange data in datagridview into an excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

I have a program in VB.Net that looks like this.

[image]

I cannot show to you all the data in my program because it has a lot of data. but please focus on the column `Category`. Please assume that all of the data in my program has its own unique data in `Category` column and each of that item might have the following data like this.

[image]

Now i created my own Excel file that looks like this.

[image]

Now here is my target, I have a button called `Print Final Transmittal` if I will click that all of the data in my program will be exported in my Excel File. I have a solution to that I can export it but my problem here is how can I group each data by category?

For Example

All of the data that has `Dry Goods` will go under the Header `Dry Goods` (the blue colored words in excel)

Here is what I've done so far. Here is the code

```
   If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Nothing to export.")
        Else
            Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
            Dim ExcelSheet As Object


            Dim rowindex As Integer = 1
            Dim total As Double = 0

            ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\SR Transmittal.xlsx")
            ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets("Transmittal Form")


            With ExcelSheet
                For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

                    If DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Dry Goods" Then

                        Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0
                        ExcelSheet.Rows(i + 16).Insert() 'Inserts row! 
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 15, columnIndex + 2).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 15, columnIndex + 3).Value = DataGridView1.Item("ItemCode", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 15, columnIndex + 4).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Description", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 15, columnIndex + 5).Value = DataGridView1.Item("RequestedQty", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 15, columnIndex + 6).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UOM", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 15, columnIndex + 7).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 15, columnIndex + 8).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Total", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 15, columnIndex + 9).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Remarks", i).Value.ToString
                        columnIndex += rowindex
                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Rice & Noodles" Then

                        Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0
                        ExcelSheet.Rows(i + 18).Insert() 'Inserts row! 
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 17, columnIndex + 2).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 17, columnIndex + 3).Value = DataGridView1.Item("ItemCode", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 17, columnIndex + 4).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Description", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 17, columnIndex + 5).Value = DataGridView1.Item("RequestedQty", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 17, columnIndex + 6).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UOM", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 17, columnIndex + 7).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 17, columnIndex + 8).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Total", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 17, columnIndex + 9).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Remarks", i).Value.ToString
                        columnIndex += rowindex
                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Oil" Then

                        Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0
                        ExcelSheet.Rows(i + 20).Insert() 'Inserts row! 
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 19, columnIndex + 2).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 19, columnIndex + 3).Value = DataGridView1.Item("ItemCode", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 19, columnIndex + 4).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Description", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 19, columnIndex + 5).Value = DataGridView1.Item("RequestedQty", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 19, columnIndex + 6).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UOM", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 19, columnIndex + 7).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 19, columnIndex + 8).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Total", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 19, columnIndex + 9).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Remarks", i).Value.ToString
                        columnIndex += rowindex
                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Beverages" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Desserts" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Meats" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Poultries" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Seafoods" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Vegetables" Then

                        Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0

                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 31, columnIndex + 2).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 31, columnIndex + 3).Value = DataGridView1.Item("ItemCode", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 31, columnIndex + 4).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Description", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 31, columnIndex + 5).Value = DataGridView1.Item("RequestedQty", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 31, columnIndex + 6).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UOM", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 31, columnIndex + 7).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 31, columnIndex + 8).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Total", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 31, columnIndex + 9).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Remarks", i).Value.ToString
                        columnIndex += rowindex
                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Other Raw Materials" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Marketing Materials" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Office Supplies" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Packaging Supplies" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Store Supplies" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Wares" Then

                        Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 41, columnIndex + 2).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 41, columnIndex + 3).Value = DataGridView1.Item("ItemCode", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 41, columnIndex + 4).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Description", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 41, columnIndex + 5).Value = DataGridView1.Item("RequestedQty", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 41, columnIndex + 6).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UOM", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 41, columnIndex + 7).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 41, columnIndex + 8).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Total", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 41, columnIndex + 9).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Remarks", i).Value.ToString
                        columnIndex += rowindex
                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Computer Equipment" Then

                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString = "Other Equipment" Then


                    End If

                Next
                .Cells(7, 4) = "To : " & ComboBox1.Text.ToUpper
                .Cells(8, 4) = "Location : " & ComboBox2.Text.ToUpper
                .Cells(7, 9) = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date
                .Cells(8, 9) = TextBox1.Text

                .Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 0
            End With

            ExcelApp.Visible = True
            ExcelSheet = Nothing
            ExcelBook = Nothing
            ExcelApp = Nothing

        End If
```

As you see on my code i try to set the starting populating data after the headers and add some conditional statement so if the `Category` reached the criteria it will go the specific location where my Header is. I also tested the code and it works fine (well no totally fine). Here it is .

[image]

the picture is right but after i scrolled down my excel file i noticed this and this one bothers me.

[image]

see the output? they did not go to there proper places. Instead they will go the header `Vegetables` and `Wares` header.

Here is my question.

Soon those data will populate and become more and more so i hope that will not be a problem in the code in the future.

====UPDATE=====

Based on my investigation it looks like that RowIndex has been added on how many data i have in datagridview so what happens is that the data is 194th row because of that.

My question is that how can I populate data group? I mean go to there respective position after the column headers based on there category.

I hope you get me and TYSM for reading my story I mean problem :D

Comment: Still looking for other answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go a different way:

- search column "A" of your excel worksheet for the current datagridview record "description" field value
- if found, insert a row beneath it and fill it with other datagridview record fields

like follows:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Nothing to export.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object, ExcelSheet As Object
        Dim found As Object '<--| this will be used to localize the current "Description" in column "A" of the excel file

        ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\SR Transmittal.xlsx")
        ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets("Transmittal Form")
        ExcelApp.Visible = True

        With ExcelSheet
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1    
                found = .Columns(1).Find(What:=DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString, LookIn:=-4163, LookAt:=1) '<--| look for the current "Category" in column "A" of "Transmittal Form" worksheet

                If found IsNot Nothing Then '<--| if you found it
                    found.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert() 'Insert row beneath the found keyword 
                    With found.Offset(1) '<-- refrence inserted row
                        .Offset(, 1).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Category", i).Value.ToString
                        .Offset(, 2).Value = DataGridView1.Item("ItemCode", i).Value.ToString
                        .Offset(, 3).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Description", i).Value.ToString
                        .Offset(, 4).Value = DataGridView1.Item("RequestedQty", i).Value.ToString
                        .Offset(, 5).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UOM", i).Value.ToString
                        .Offset(, 6).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value.ToString
                        .Offset(, 7).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Total", i).Value.ToString
                        .Offset(, 8).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Remarks", i).Value.ToString
                    End With
                End If
            Next
            .Cells(7, 4) = "To : " & ComboBox1.Text.ToUpper
            .Cells(8, 4) = "Location : " & ComboBox2.Text.ToUpper
            .Cells(7, 9) = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date
            .Cells(8, 9) = TextBox1.Text

            .Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 0
        End With

        ExcelApp.Visible = True
        found = Nothing
        ExcelSheet = Nothing
        ExcelBook = Nothing
        ExcelApp = Nothing    
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hello Sir this is the first time i will test sorry for the late reply its been 3 days since there was All Souls and All Saints Day. I hope we can have a conversation about this solution in case theres a problem, I wil try it now

Comment: Sir are you online? I have some question and sir its not working :(

Comment: "Not working" isn't a useful description at all: please give details about what's not working (actual behavior against expected one) and what errors (if any) are being thrown.

Comment: Ahmm sir its working just finished the program and TYSM for the help sorry for the late update :D

Comment: Sir i have a question, For example I hide the column that used in segregating the data the result is no output sir

Comment: Well I'm not by any PC by now so I can't help you. Furthermore this is a new issue so you need to post a new question along with your code attempts and all relevant details about minimal environment reproducing the issue